# For a Poisson random variable $X$ with mean $\lambda$. It is twice as likely for $X$ to be $\lt1$ as it is for $X$ to be $ \ge1$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

For a Poisson random variable $ X $ with mean $ \lambda $ it is found that it is twice as likely for $ X $ to
be $ \lt 1 $ as it is for $ X $ to be $ \ge 1 $. Find $ \lambda $.

I know that the solution is: $ 0.405 $ but I would like to ask how to get to that number.
On Internet I found that the process is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    P\left(X \lt 1\right) &= 2P\left(X \gt 1\right) \\
    P\left(X \lt 1\right) &= 2 - 2P\left(X \lt 1\right) \\
    P\left(X \lt 1\right) + 2P\left(X \lt 1\right) &= 2 \\
    3P\left(X \lt 1\right) &= 2 \\
    P\left(X \lt 1\right) &= \frac{2}{3} \; \text{and then you compute the rest.}
\end{aligned}
$$
My question is: after the first step, I don't understand why we have to do "$ 2 - 2P\left(X \lt 1\right) $". What does the first "$ 2 $" stands for? For example, if I was asked to find the value knowing that it is thrice as likely for the value to be greater than $ 1 $, would that $ 2 $ become a $ 3 $ or what is the process behind it?
Thanks.

Comment: In the first line you need $X \geq 1$ rather than  $X>1$. $P(X>1)=1-P(X \leq 1)$. Multiply by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as $X$ is Poisson distributed, $X$ can take on values $0,1,2,...$. Thus, $P(X<1)=P(X=0)$. Using this, and that $P(X\ge1)=1-P(X=0)$, the given constraint that $P(X<1)=2P(X\ge1)$ is equivalent to:
$$P(X=0)=2(1-P(X=0))$$
$$e^{-\lambda}=2(1-e^{-\lambda})$$
$$e^{-\lambda}=2-2e^{-\lambda}$$
the two preceding lines are the same way they got the '$2$' that you are asking about. It is just distributing the '$2$' in $2(1-P(X<1))$. Continuing on:
$$3e^{-\lambda}=2$$
$$\lambda=-ln(\tfrac23)\approx.405$$